# How to set a Custom date field to read only in Azure Devops and still be able to populate value in it?

Tags: azure-devops

We have a requirement where a custom date field needs to be set to read only and a date value should be populated in it from another Date field. Is it possible to achieve this in Azure DevOps?

We are using inherited process and have two custom fields - Estimated Start date and Target Start Date. Below is the requirement -

1. Estimated start date needs to be read only and Target Start date can be modified.
2. Whenever Target Start Date is set initially, the same value needs to be populated to Estimated Start Date automatically. However, if the target start date is modified, the estimated start date should have its original value and shouldn't get modified thereafter.

We were able to achieve the second part by creating couple of rules. However this doesn't work if Estimated start date is set to read only.

Is there a workaround for this? or is this a limitation in Azure DevOps?